# SED not adding a first line to .csv file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am doing a project for school and my head has gone through 3 walls with how many times I have bashed it. the project is to ask a name and color and assign each to a variable then make a directory from the color variable in the /tmp directory. create a .csv file with header, pull the information from a given .txt file out of order and add only select columns. I have gotten to the point of adding the columns  but no matter what i do I cant get sed to add a header or import the information from the .txt file.

as you can see i have tried multiple ways to modify the file but I dont know enough yet to make it work

the input file format is as follows

```
1. 734-44-2041 James SMITH jsmith@beltec.us 360-555-4778 360-555-0158
```

and it should look like

```
james,smith,james.smith@beltec.us,734-44-2041-000
```

I am assuming that the 3 commas are intended to be 0's at the end

this is the code I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
#interactive=

#variables 
color=/tmp/$color
csvfile=/tmp/blue/midterm.csv

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
echo "you should use the -c or -C flags
exit
fi

#adding the -c flag and setting the filename variable 
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do 
case $1 in
-c | -C )   shift
        filename=$1
        ;;

* )     echo "you should use the -c flag"
        exit 1
esac
shift
done

#get user's name
echo "what is your name"
read user_name

#get fav color from user
echo "what is your favorate color"
read color

#make the fov color directory
if [ ! -f /tmp/$color ]; then
mkdir /tmp/$color
else
echo "bad luck $user_name"
exit 1
fi

#cd into the directory
cd /tmp/$color

#make a csv file in /temp/$color
touch midterm.csv

akw '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; print "Firstname","lastname","Maildomain","Password" }
{ print $2,$3,$4,$1 }
' "$filename" > "/tmp/$color/midterm.csv"
```

Comment: I have commented out several lines that I thought might be effecting the code but none of them did the trick

Answer (score 1):

sed by default outputs its results on the standard output.

In case you need to overwrite the old file use `-i` (or better `-i.bak`) to keep previous file version in `<filename>.bak`

Moreover in case you need to add something only at the beginning of the file use following syntax:

```
sed '1iYOUR_TEXT'
```

Answer (score 1):

You never need sed when you're using awk. All you need to create a header + content is:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; print "Firstname", "Lastname", "Maildomain", "Password" }
    { print $3, $4, $5, $2 }
' "$filename" > "/tmp/$color/midterm.csv"
```

Or if your input file isn't a CSV as it seems not to be by your updated question:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS=","; print "Firstname", "Lastname", "Maildomain", "Password" }
    { print $3, $4, $5, $2 }
' "$filename" > "/tmp/$color/midterm.csv"
```

Comment: works great except now i get 3 commas at the beginning of each line

Comment: Then there's something non-obvious about the input that you haven't shown us yet. Please edit your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you write a tool to parse that input to produce that output.

Comment: i have added 2 lines from the file above the code I have so far

Comment: There's the problem then - your input file isn't a CSV. So just remove the `FS=` from my script so it treats the input file as space-separated values instead of a CSV.

Comment: awesome works like a charm thank you and I hope to not have to bug you folks anymore on this thank you again